# Auto filling datagridview based on cell double click in another datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview for billing. I added one seperate datagridview to display inventory items alone. so if i double click on an item name it should appear in the billing datagridview column names items name and also auto colmpete other columns such as mrp tax etc. How to do this? I added a celldoubleclick event in items name listing datagridview and retrieving the cell value like this.

```
private void dgv_ItemNamePOS_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string a = dgv_ItemNamePOS.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        dgv_POS.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = a.ToString();


    }
```

the value is appearing in billing gridview item name column. I added a value changed event in billing datagridview but its not firing.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            con.Open();
            if (dgv_POS.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Item_Code from Items where Name=@Name AND Activate='Yes'", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", dgv_POS.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                string k = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                dgv_POS.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = k;

            }
```

i want to add this item name to the next free row in billing datagridview. Can someone help me in solving this. I want to auto fill billing datagridview cell based on item name in another datagridview which contains only item names upon double click.

see the below picture to get my idea.
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlGrQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't understand everything you need, but if you just need to show the details of each bill item, check the following:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<BillItem> _Items = new List<BillItem>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn clmItemName = new DataColumn("clmItemName", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add(clmItemName);
        dt.Rows.Add("Parle-G");
        dt.Rows.Add("Kardjack");

        dgv_ItemNamePOS.DataSource = dt;

        // to simulate items' details in database
        _Items.Add(new BillItem() { No = 1, ItemName = "Parle-G", Code = "P-G", MRP = "***" });
        _Items.Add(new BillItem() { No = 1, ItemName = "Kardjack", Code = "K", MRP = "@@@" });
    }

    class BillItem
    {
        public int No { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string MRP { get; set; }
    }

    private void dgv_ItemNamePOS_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string a = dgv_ItemNamePOS.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        dgv_POS.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = a.ToString();

       BillItem billItem = _Items.First(item => item.ItemName == a);

        dgv_POS.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = billItem.No.ToString();
        dgv_POS.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = billItem.Code.ToString();
        dgv_POS.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = billItem.MRP;
    }
}
```